# Как синхронизировать mysql БД в phpmystorm/workbench?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть на сервере база данных, рабочая. Есть база на локалке, пока написал модуль они стали существенно различаться.

Как синхронизировать базы? Имею mysql workbench, но больше нравится работать в phpstorm. Можно ли выполнить синхронизацию конкретных таблиц и как это сделать?

К примеру некоторые таблицы залить на рабочий сервер, другие - с раб.сервера на локалку.

Comment: Так а что у вас изменилось-то, данные или структура?

Comment: @D-side на рабочем добавились данные, на локалке добавились новые таблицы.